# Cross Validation and model training

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-evaluation

I am using `sklearn` to train two models and compare their outcome with each other but I am not sure how to evaluate the models. As I have little data (approx. 300 data points) I want to use cross validation to train my model. So I have read that it is only used for hyper parameter tuning which I am already doing with `GridSearchCV`.

To train my model with more data I would want to use cross validation as well for training purposes. Does it make sense to do so?

My division of data would look like this:

1. 80% of data: train/validation with cross validation and hyperparameter tuning (so the model is trained as well already in this step)
2. 20% of data: test set and measuring MAE and RMSE as well as analysing prediction made by trained model

or should I do it that way before using GridSearch:

Split data into three data chunks:

1. 60% of data for training
2. 20% of data for testing
3. 20% of data for validation

**First step:** Use the validation set in GridSearch and find the best parameters based on validation.

**Second step:** Train model with best parameters found by grid search with training set

**Third step:** Test model and calculate MAE and RSME on test set and as well as analysing prediction made by trained model

If both evaluation methods are not right, I would be grateful for any tips how to find the best way to evaluate my models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Divide your data into training set and test set (e.g. 80%, 20%).
2. Perform the Grid Search (which uses k-fold cross validation) on the training set for two models and pick best parameters. `GridSearchCV` will divide the training set into $k$ train/validate splits on its own.
3. Use the test set to compare the final models.